# base64 image not display in mvc view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, ado.net

i want to display image in mvc Image is store in database type of file is image and i want to get image first i am converting bytes and then i want to display in view i am trying everything but image is not display only blank rectangle show .

```
conn.Open();

using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select  isnull(ClientPic,'') as ClientPic from MembersDetail where Srno=1 and MemberShipID='" + clsCommon._MembershipID + "'", conn))
{
    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
    DataTable mdt_pic = new DataTable();
    ad.Fill(mdt_pic);

    for (int i = 0; i < mdt_pic.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        ViewBag.Pic = obj_u.ClientPic = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])mdt_pic.Rows[i]["ClientPic"]);   
    }
    conn.Close();
}

<img src="@ViewBag.Pic" alt="User" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use base64. You should get the file as a FileContentResult

```
public ActionResult GetFile() // note should accept an id or something
{
    byte[] bytes = null;
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select  isnull(ClientPic,'') as ClientPic from MembersDetail where Srno=1 and MemberShipID='" + clsCommon._MembershipID + "'", conn))
    {
        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
        DataTable mdt_pic = new DataTable();
        ad.Fill(mdt_pic);

        for (int i = 0; i < mdt_pic.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
             bytes = (byte[])mdt_pic.Rows[i]["ClientPic"];
        }
        conn.Close();

    }
    return new FileContentResult(bytes, "image/png"); // content type may be different for any file
}
```

Then call the action in src:

```
<img src="GetFile" alt="User" />
```